# Spring session creates new session without authentication after session timeout

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-session

I'm using `@EnableMongoHttpSession` in the `HttpSessionConfig` class. So, when a url is hit from a browser, it asks for authentication. On a successful login, a new document is created in the Mongo 'Sessions' collection. After session timeout, the document is deleted from the collection. Everything goes fine till this.

However, when the same url is hit from browser, a new session is created without authentication automatically (New session document is created).

Security configuration used is as below:

```
httpSec.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/welcomeUrl").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/user/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN").anyRequest()
    .authenticated()
    .and().httpBasic()
    .sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1).expiredUrl("/welcomeUrl");
```

Please someone let me know what I'm missing here.

**EDIT:** On investigation, found that when url is hit from browser, and after login, cookie is seen in developer tools. When url is hit the next time, I could see "Authorization: Basic...." and "Cookie: SESSION....." parts in Request Header.

After session timeout, since the Basic authorization header provides username, new session is created without asking for authentication.

How do we make Spring boot consider cookie for session creation instead of Basic Authorization header?